# Build only the necessary with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

repo like this:

```
repo
  - service1
  - service2
  - service3
```

now I have put on the main directory the jenkinsfile to build and do some stuff, but I want to rebuild only service 1 if I change samething in the subfolder service1, how can i can do?
for now the pipeline is like this, but I want to make it better because now I rebuild everything:

```
pipeline{
agent any
stages {
     stage('Build') {
     steps {
        script{
                sh '''
                cd security_manager;
                STAGING=true;
                sbt " -DSTAGING=$STAGING; reload; clean; compile;  docker:publish";
                '''
                sh '''
                cd storage_manager;
                STAGING=true;
                sbt " -DSTAGING=$STAGING; reload; clean; compile;  docker:publish";
                '''
                sh '''
                cd ;
                STAGING=true;
                sbt " -DSTAGING=$STAGING; reload; clean; compile;  docker:publish";
                '''
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to place same if/else between the sh script but  don't know what condition i had to do, because I want to use the git diff between the $GIT_COMMIT and the last commit to check the file, but in the if statement condition I can't put shell script

Answer (score 1):

You only need to find difference between last and current commit:

```
 def diff = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git diff @~..@')
```

Then it is up to You how You have to handle that. The easiest way is to extract only changed directory from every line of diff